# Installing packages and warn message

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, package

When installing packages using npm in vscode, I get certain WARN messages like below. Should I worry about them or is it okay?

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})      
npm WARN backend@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN backend@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Comment: `fsevents` doesn't run on Windows, but as the message says it's an *optional* dependency. If you want to know what it does, see e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents.

Answer (score 1):

When installing any package using npm you usually don’t need to worry about warnings. You can run npm with the below option to only see the errors:

```
--loglevel=error
```

In your case:
The warning is shown for fsevents, which only runs on OSX and cannot be installed on windows and linux.

**When the Warning says something like this:**

```
NPM WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3
```

Although your application and functionality might be working as intended, the above warning means that the package is deprecated and the devs no longer support it.

So, in this case it is best if you update that particular package to a more recent version as the deprecated version probably has some issues. For example, if you have the Warning like above for core-js, you can install the latest package using the command:

```
npm install --save core-js@^3
```

Comment: Thanks, and can I ignore the warn which says '.... is no longer maintained' ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include this kind of  scenario. Please check it out.